# How would graph the look like of Chemical potential vs temperature for BEC in 1D and 2D

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

I tried to work this out myself but I couldn't. Is there any notes or books that have a graph of of Chemical potential vs temperature for Bose-Einstein Condensate in 1D and 2D

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem), the Bose-Einstein condensed phase *does not exist* (for finite temperature) in 1D and 2D, for free systems.

You could have a BEC in a 2D harmonic trap.